# How to get started in game development with Lua without LOVE or any game engine

Tags: lua

Recently, I've been wanting to get into Lua, and I just started to. I was wondering if it is possible to make a game, without the LOVE engine, like are there any built-in libraries I can use or external libraries? How would I install these libraries?

I am using the ZeroBrane Studio IDE, not plugins for Java IDEs.

I know this is pretty vague, but I have done some research, and most of it is either Roblox tutorials or LOVE tutorials.

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for game engines and libraries is off topic here. Why don't you want to use an engine?

Comment: @Vaillancourt to learn more and to have actual challenge

Comment: Questions asking "how to get started" or "which technology/libraries to use" are not on-topic for this StackExchange. A quick search for [how to compile an executable from Lua](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=compile+lua+executable) or how to [use graphics libraries in Lua](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lua+graphics+library) turns up [very promising hits](https://github.com/stetre/moonlibs) on the first page that are not Roblox or LOVE related, so you might just need to adjust your search terms. Try these resources, then you should be in a position to ask a more specific question we can help with here.